How disable Hibernate cache in a subgraph
This is just a simplyfication of the problem.
I've declared an entity graph in order to retrieve all data from the main entity (Order) and its related sub-entities (Person).
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "orderGraph",
    attributeNodes = {
            @NamedAttributeNode("id"),
            @NamedAttributeNode("code"),
            @NamedAttributeNode("comment"),
            @NamedAttributeNode(
                    value = "person",
                    subgraph = "person-subGraph")
    },
    subgraphs = {
            @NamedSubgraph(
                    name = "person-subGraph",
                    attributeNodes = {
                            @NamedAttributeNode("id"),
                            @NamedAttributeNode("firstname")
                            @NamedAttributeNode("lastname")
                    })
   })
public class Order {
    private Integer id;
    private String code;
    private String comment;
    private Person person;
}

public class Person {
    private Integer id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
}

The first time I retrieve the order id=1 using eGraph I get also the related Person (example id=1, firstname=Michelle, lastname=Obama).
But if I update the comment of an order in this way (just an example to explain the problem):
Order order = // read the order from repository
order.setComment("my first order");  // update the comment
order.setPerson(new Person(1));  // for some reason I need to specify again the id of the person related to the order, without read the complete person-record

and after the update if I read the order using the eGraph I retrieve this data (in JSON format just to view clearly the all fields):
order: {
    "id": 1,
    "code": "C1",
    "comment": "my first order",
    "person": {
        "id": 1
        "firstname": null
        "lastname": null
    }
}

The Person with id=1 is saved in Hibernate cache only with the id, so firstname and lastname is null.
I've tried to set "hint" to the query with SpecHints.HINT_SPEC_CACHE_RETRIEVE_MODE = "BYPASS", but the firstname and lastname is always null.
The only solution I've found is to call a entityManager.clear() before retrieve data using eGraph, but my question is: is there a solution to achieve the same result without invoke a "clear()"?

Instead of new Person(1) get a reference to the entity with entityManager.getReference(id, Person.class) or use getById if using Spring Data JPA. This will not actually go to the database but create a lazy proxy which will eventually go to the database when needed. Although it is a bit strange you need to set it in the first place, which seems to be the actual issue.

@M.Deinum thanks a lot, very usefull. I was convinced that getReferenceById and getById automatically execute a query. Replacing new Person(1) with getReferenceById(1) I've no more need to call flush and clear, and primarily without run unnecessary query.
